# SQL Statement help in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
Sub Bind_dgList()
Dim strCommand As String     
Dim strConnect As String     
Dim DBDataAdapter_Leads As OleDbDataAdapter     
Dim DBConnection_List As OleDbConnection     
Dim DBDataSet_Leads As DataSet
Dim DBDataView_Leads As DataView

strConnect = GetDBConnectionString()     
DBConnection_List = New OleDbConnection(strConnect)     
strCommand = "SELECT * Manager FROM tblList ORDER BY Names"     
DBDataAdapter_Leads = New OleDbDataAdapter(strCommand, DBConnection_List)     DBDataSet_Leads = New DataSet     
DBDataAdapter_Leads.Fill(DBDataSet_Leads, "tblList")     
DBDataView_Leads = New DataView(DBDataSet_Leads.Tables("tblList"))      
dgList.DataSource = DBDataView_Leads     
dgList.DataBind() 

End Sub
```

### Can anyone help me with the above code? I want to select distinct record of names. Some of the names are repeating. May I know how to do it?

I have used all the above. But There is an error showing.

First error : Server Error in '/wwwroot' Application. Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '* Manager'. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '* Manager'.

Source Error: Line 71: DBDataAdapter_FocalLeads = New OleDbDataAdapter(strCommand, DBConnection_AgentList) Line 72: DBDataSet_FocalLeads = New DataSet Line 73: DBDataAdapter_FocalLeads.Fill(DBDataSet_FocalLeads, "tblAgentList") Line 74: DBDataView_FocalLeads = New DataView(DBDataSet_FocalLeads.Tables("tblAgentList"))

Line 75:
Second Error : DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'FieldId'. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'FieldId'.

Source Error: Line 75: Line 76: dgAgentList.DataSource = DBDataView_FocalLeads Line 77: dgAgentList.DataBind() Line 78: End Sub

Line 79:
But When am using this there is no error, but the manager names are repeating. strCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblAgentList ORDER BY Manager"

Am doing this to mass edit and update the records. If I can get help in doing the mass updating I can ignore this page. Now I have to edit line by line. So if there is change in a managers role and its repeating 5 times. I need to manually edit one by to update. So is there a way to do a mass update?

Thank you for the help.. I really appreciate.. :)

---

I have used all the above. But There is an error showing.

**First error :** Server Error in '/wwwroot' Application.
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '* Manager'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '* Manager'.

Source Error: 
Line 71:         DBDataAdapter_FocalLeads = New OleDbDataAdapter(strCommand, DBConnection_AgentList)
Line 72:         DBDataSet_FocalLeads = New DataSet
Line 73:         DBDataAdapter_FocalLeads.Fill(DBDataSet_FocalLeads, "tblAgentList")
Line 74:         DBDataView_FocalLeads = New DataView(DBDataSet_FocalLeads.Tables("tblAgentList"))

### Line 75:

**Second Error :** DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'FieldId'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'FieldId'.

Source Error: 
Line 75: 
Line 76:         dgAgentList.DataSource = DBDataView_FocalLeads
Line 77:         dgAgentList.DataBind()
Line 78:     End Sub

### Line 79:

But When am using this there is no error, but the manager names are repeating.
strCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblAgentList ORDER BY Manager"

Am doing this to mass edit and update the records. If I can get help in doing the mass updating I can ignore this page.
Now I have to edit line by line. So if there is change in a managers role and its repeating 5 times. I need to manually edit one by to update. So is there a way to do a mass update?

Thank you for the help.. I really appreciate.. :)

Comment: I've merged your unregistered accounts. You now have control over all of your questions. Please consider associating an OpenID with this one, or you're likely to lose access again if you lose the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```
SELECT * FROM Manager tblList ORDER BY Names
```

or

```
SELECT *, Manager FROM tblList ORDER BY Names
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your SQL statement like this

> SELECT DISTINCT Names FROM Manager
>   ORDER BY Names

I don't think

> SELECT * FROM

will work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest of the code works all you should need to do is change this line

`strCommand = "SELECT * Manager FROM tblList ORDER BY Names"`

to this

`strCommand = "SELECT DISTINCT * Manager FROM tblList ORDER BY Names"`